# all pages are loading except index page?

Tags: .htaccess

I've a htaccess code here.All the pages will work with redirect except the home page. I made changes in conf file also but no use please help. It says object not found when I click the home page link.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{HTTP} =on

RewriteRule ^home/?$         index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^about-us/?$         about.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^quick-service/?$     quick_service.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^road-side/?$     road_side.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^video-visualization/?$     video_visual.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^distance-approach/?$     distance_approach.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pickup-drop/?$     pickup_drop.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^checking-status/?$     checking_status.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^genuine-parts/?$     genuine_parts.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^book-vehicle/?$     book_vehicle.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^Sign-In/?$     login.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^Register/?$     register.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^purchase-parts/?$     purchase.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$     contact.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^service-centers/?$     service_centers.php [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Does either / or /home work?

Comment: "/" works "/home" doesn't work

Comment: Which apache version do you use?

Comment: version 2.0 apache